# What is difference between designed initializer and convenience initializer in swift?

Tags: swift, initialization

```
class RecipeIngredient: Food {
    var quantity: Int
    init(name: String, quantity: Int) {
        self.quantity = quantity
        super.init(name: name)
    }
    override convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init(name: name, quantity: 1)
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your post and use [Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

The [Apple Documentation Initialization Section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html);

has a large explanation underneath the heading: Class Inheritance and Initialization

Most of the explanation is then under the subheading: Designated Initializers and Convenience Initializers

However a simplified explanation is that a designated initializers are the default initialisers for a given object. They usually pass an object's exact requirements as parameters. Whereas convenience initialisers in most cases have less parameters to pass and will fill in the gaps with defaulted values.

It is often the case that a convenience initializer will call the object's default initializer with some defaulted values.